# photo album like controls

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am making a camera app a where user can make videos and take pictures. What I am doing is I am saving all the movies and pictures in my apps document directory. I don't want to automatically save them to users photo album. What I would like to present to the user is view that behaves similar to how Photo Album works meaning I would like to show him all the movies and pictures he has taken and give him buttons to check and save the ones he like and delete the ones he wants to discard.

Now here's my question, Do I create a custom uitableview, present small cropped resized pictures, add uitoolbar at the bottom and add my own custom "Save", "Discard" and "preview image/Video" buttons or is there already something available ootb in iOS 5 Xcode 4.2 that I can use?

I have searched cocoa controls website and found many image Picker controls but none that work like as simple "save to photo album", "delete photo" or "Preview Photo / Video" features. Is there any sample control available that I can use and probably extend it? Trust me I have been googling for a while now

Looking for something like this. The people who made this, are they using UITableView or UICollectionView or neither?

[image]

Comment: check this link https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController

Comment: @Rushabh - already did. Its more of a image picker. I guess I can extend it though I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Here is a very cool sample project

https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to go to IOS 6, you could try this tutorial (2 parts):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12
http://www.raywenderlich.com/22417/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-22

Comment: Hi Vincent, is UICollectionView available in iOS 5? If so then I maybe able to use this tutorial in my iOS 5.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView
Got it from: http://oleb.net/blog/2012/09/uicollectionview/ (the bottom comment)

Comment: I tried downloading and compiling this project in Xcode 4.2 but unfortunately its has tons of compiler errors. I tried both 4.3 and 5.0 deployment target but to no help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Nope, apart from updating to the latest XCode that is, but I assume that's not an option :). Hopefully someone else can help you out!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 14, this is now available in [the new Photos picker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/selecting_photos_and_videos_in_ios).